# Date manipulation periods

Tags: python, excel, csv, analytics, etl

I have this problem  for work. So I have this dataset as follows:

```
Client  Date    Transaction Num
A   7/20/2017   1
A   7/26/2017   1
A   7/31/2017   1
A   8/23/2017   2
A   8/31/2017   2
A   9/11/2017   2
A   9/19/2017   3
A   9/27/2017   3
A   10/4/2017   3
B   6/1/2017    1
B   6/29/2017   1
B   7/6/2017    2
B   8/27/2017   3
B   9/28/2017   4
B   10/16/2017  4
B   11/30/2017  5
```

What I need to do is generate the transaction num based on the date for each client as follows:

For the starting date (for client A, it is 7/20/17), I need to assign a starting transaction Number = 1. Then for every 30 days from this starting date, I need to increment the transaction number by one. So 30 days from 7/20/17 is 8/19/17, so all dates falling within this range get transaction num =1, then if they exceed, the transaction number increments by one for every 30 days from starting date. This pattern goes on, so 30 days from 8/19/17 is 9/18/17, so dates within this range gets transaction num =2, and after 9/18/17, gets transaction num = 3 and so on.

I need to do this for a large excel. Any help would be appreciated. If it easier in python, please let me know as well.

Thanks,
Sammy

Comment: Are the dates going to be in ascending order like you've shown them (apart from the first of B which maybe should be A)?

Comment: Yes, for each client, the dates will be ascending order (I corrected the error on first row of B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, possibly multiple sollutions but I came up with the one below:

[image]

So in C1 enter this formula:

```
=FLOOR(ROUND(B1-MIN(IF($A$1:$A$17=A1,$B$1:$B$17)),1)/30,1)+1
```

Confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, and drag your formula down.

*Note: Sorry for the difference in layout of dates, I have to deal with Dutch version of Excel :)*

**EDIT: Explaination**

Step 1 - Get minimum date corresponding to Cell A1:

```
=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$17=A1,$B$1:$B$17))
```

Step 2 - Get difference of cell B1 and minimmum and round it of. Doesn't matter if its one or 0 decimals:

```
=ROUND(B1-MIN(IF($A$1:$A$17=A1,$B$1:$B$17)),1)
```

Step 3 - Devide difference through 30 days:

```
=ROUND(B1-MIN(IF($A$1:$A$17=A1,$B$1:$B$17)),1)/30
```

Step 4 - Make sure you round of this outcome to below (probably bad english) with floor function to its closest multiple you want to round to. In this case it will be 1.

```
=FLOOR(ROUND(B1-MIN(IF($A$1:$A$17=A1,$B$1:$B$17)),1)/30,1)
```

Step 5 - Now we just need to add 1 to this outcome to prevent starting at 0

```
=FLOOR(ROUND(B1-MIN(IF($A$1:$A$17=A1,$B$1:$B$17)),1)/30,1)+1
```

Confirm all through CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: @Sammy7, I hope my explaination will do :)

Comment: Cool, I get everything except for how does the formula know the next client, for instance "B", is encountered and then to use a new set of minimum dates?

Comment: Nice answer. Can also use MINIFS if you are lucky enough to have Excel 365 :-)

Comment: Cause you Will drag the formula down it will look in a column of that row. The lookup for minimum value searches whole b column for minimum value while criteria in a column must be that lookup value

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are in order, you could just do a VLOOKUP to get the first one and subtract, but @JvdV's answer is more general

```
=INT((B2-VLOOKUP(A2,A:B,2,FALSE))/30)+1
```

Comment: Nice  one Tom!  :)